# Where to start with Visual Studio for Database Developers

Tags: visual-studio, datadude

Does anyone have a list of advice, best practices, getting started guides, etc. for VS for Database Developers?

Answer (score 2):

stick to sql scripts?

Seriously.... the visual tools for DB creation make it harder to build and maintain a DB In my opinion.

Comment: The tools available in VS2010 beta are really great an definate improvement over ssms imo. I can't speak for 2008 since i only use professional, not TS.

Comment: VS2010 appears to be script based. SS Management Studio has far more visual editors.

Comment: @Paul, what do you think of the folder structures? I find it odd that keys are stored separately from the tables they affect.